# How do I perform a T-Test on mulitple columns on specfic rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, iteration

I have a pandas datafrmae and have performed a t test on the first column using values ctrl 4 values (rows 2:5) versus 3 KO values (rows 6:8). The T-test worked on the first column. However can someone please tell me how I iterate over every column and perform this test using rows 2:5 and 6:8 throughout. Here is my code and my DF is names r1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX9px.png)

```
from scipy import stats
a=r1.iloc[2:6, 0]
b=r1.iloc[6:9, 0]
stats.ttest_ind(a, b, axis=0, equal_var=True)
```

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Just a note - if this data is highly related or all from the same source, make sure you are using some kind of correction for multiple tests (e.g. Bonferroni).

Comment: You should be able to do that by just passing all the columns at once. Meaning, doing `a = r1.iloc[2:6, :]`, `b = r1.iloc[6:9, :]` and then passing them to ttest_ind `stats.ttest_ind(a, b, axis=0, equal_var=True)` should work. This will return the result as a tuple of arrays of length `N` where `N` are the number of columns in your dataset.

Comment: Thank you Tirth for that very helpful response. I followed your advice, `a=r1.iloc[2:6, 1:]` and`b=r1.iloc[6:9, 1:]` then  `stats.ttest_ind(a, b, axis=0, equal_var=True) `. The reason I added  `1:` was because the first column is the index. I get the following error "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable sqrt method". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Another possibility that I tried was to iterate throught the columns but this just repeatedly prints out the p value of the same column; `a=0` `b=0` `d=[]` `for x in range(0,3000):` `a=r1.iloc[2:6, x]` `b=r1.iloc[6:9, x]` `c=stats.ttest_ind(a, b, axis=0, equal_var=True)` `a=a+1` `b=b+1` `d.append(c)`  `print(d)`